# Google sheets - how can you filter by a cell by typing it in a column

Tags: google-sheets

I have imported data from a from and i would like filter the answers against the data automatically.
Right now i have to right now i have to click on the arrow box, click clear and then type type in word in the search box.

is there a way to make a cell into a search box?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ri7pmkGs2uY

found this on youtube  =query('Form Responses 1'!1:1003, "select * where B = """&B1&""" ")﻿